# Run transaction queries in Yii 1.x

Tags: php, yii, transactions

I am trying to run a transactional query using Yii 1.x - this should basically rollback all the queries if there is a problem, can people confirm this is the correct way to run transactions using Yii 1?

```
// data comes from a csv
 $transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
    try
    {

        if (($handle = fopen($path, "r")) !== false) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
                if ($currentRow == 1) {
                    $header = $this->import_fields(array_map('strtolower', $data));
                    $currentRow++;
                    continue;
                } else {
                    $data = array_combine($header, $data);
                    $csv_import_model = null;

                    if (!empty($data['username'])) {
                        $csv_import_model = StudentImportForm::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                            'username' => $data['username'],
                            'organisation_id' => user()->data->organisation->getViewOrgId()
                        ));
                    }

                    if (is_null($csv_import_model)) {
                        $csv_import_model = new StudentImportForm();
                        $isNew = true;
                    } else {
                        $isNew = false;
                    }

                    $csv_import_model->scenario = 'import';
                    $csv_import_model->setAttributes($data);
                    $csv_import_model->unsetAttributes(array('password'));

                    if ($csv_import_model->validate()) {

                        if (in_array($csv_import_model->username, $processedUsername)) {
                            $csv_import_model->addError('username', sprintf('Duplicate username (%1$s) found in csv file. which may already exists on row number %2$s.', $csv_import_model->username, (array_search($csv_import_model->username, $processedUsername) + 1)));
                        } else {

                            if ($csv_import_model->save()) {

                                if ($isNew) {
                                    $this->csv_results['inserted'] = $this->csv_results['inserted']+1;
                                } else {
                                    $this->csv_results['updated'] = $this->csv_results['updated']+1;
                                }

                            } else {
                                $this->csv_results['error'][$currentRow] = $csv_import_model->getErrors();
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $csv_import_model->csv_index = $currentRow;
                        $this->csv_results['error'][$currentRow] = $csv_import_model->getErrors();
                    }

                    $processedUsername[] = $csv_import_model->username;

                    $currentRow++;
                    Yii::getLogger()->flush(false);
                }
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }

        $transaction->commit();
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $transaction->rollback();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$model->save() doesn't throw an exception in case it fails. It returns true or false. In order to rollback the entire block, you must manually throw an exception if save() returns false. Try something like this:

```
$errors = null;
try {
    if ($csv_import_model->save()) {
        // continue with whatever logic you have
        $transaction->commit();
    }else{
        $errors = 'Error when saving';
        throw new Exception('Could not save model');
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
   //Do some logging here
   $transaction->rollback();
   if($errors != null){
       Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', $errors);
   }
}
```

Comment: where should the transaction->commit() sit in this code?

Comment: I edited my answer to put the commit() in the right Place, right after the save(). If you had more saves, you should put a single commit at the very end of the last save

Comment: Thanks that really helps a lot - is it possible to log/save the lines of my csv that have thrown an Exception to be displayed within a flash session message?

Comment: Yes. I edited my answer again. Just make sure you have a variable to store the error messages outside the try-catch block and add whatever errors messsage to it (See the docs for detailed error message handling: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#getErrors-detail").